# How to figure out why transaction with ERC20 contract failed

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, contract-debugging

Real simple question, actually... I have this contract :

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x5a7c68255698d64f07C38D6DF3d5bea073328da1

I'm trying to send tokens around some accounts, but they keep failing. I cannot figure out if i'm using the wrong addresses or if the amount is wrong.

How do I go about debugging this? (I use Web3, nodejs )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `transfer()` function directly, not `transferFrom()`.

`transferFrom()` should be used when there are tokens approved for your account.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed was the problem. What is a use-case for TransferFrom though?

Comment: `transferFrom()` is used when somebody else approved an allowance for you and you spend their tokens. But the tokens are always in their posession. They can approve multiple accounts to spend their tokens.